# How to define a type for a template in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-generics

I'm going to define a type where I can store the response from various API that has similar responses.

The response looks like

```
type TResponse<E> = {
   Code: number;
   Message: string;
   Result: {
      [i: string]:  Array<E>;
      Count: number;
   };
   Status: string;
}
```

`[i: string]` can be anything except for `Count` depending on the API design, for example, `Rows`, `Values`, `Logs`, etc...
This for now gives me an error, because of the `Count` property conflicts with `[i: string]`.

P.S. I'm using the typescript version ^3.9.7

Comment: I can get this fixed by using ```{  [i: string]:  Array<E> | number; Count: number; };``` for `Result` but not sure if this is the best solution

Comment: I don't think the TS compiler will let you express what you want because [index type definitions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) cannot co-exist with any object properties. Perhaps store `Count` outside as a sibling of `Result`? (i.e. `ResultCount`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an intersection type:

```ts
type TResponse<E> = {
   Code: number;
   Message: string;
   Result: {
      [i: string]: Array<E>;
    } & {
      Count: number;
   };
   Status: string;
}

declare const response: TResponse<string>;
response.Result.Count; // number
response.Result.abc; // string[]
```

Note that this is slightly unsafe, which is why TS requires that all properties are assignable to its index signature:

```ts
declare const key: string;
response.Result[key]; // string[] even though key could be Count
```

Also, trying to create objects like this requires a type assertion:

```ts
const response2: TResponse<string> = {
   Code: 0,
   Message: '',
   // Type '{ Count: number; }' is not assignable to type ...
   Result: {
      Count: 1
   },
   Status: ''
}

const response3 = {
   Code: 0,
   Message: '',
   Result: {
      Count: 1
   },
   Status: ''
} as TResponse<string>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgShAzmA9gO0RAPAUQHxQC8UA3gFBSUDCKAJhAFxRoCuAtgEYQBOA3BZQCySRAEMA5oyiJg3AJZpx-SlASIWAG2BNyKlQG0A+nKYz5igLpMAgt26iQuPMpUBfKADJSAvTRZptZnYuPh9XFygAZWBRYBZEU1kFJTJXMjJ6AGMNUW5oTPQZKDzkQql4JFQMbDNk5zISqswAOjVNYGa-AN4oAHpeoM4eBsqy1qR25tEOTJ7+6STFfQt0rJy8qAKMYCgAawgQRPMUxrG2rX19kAs5gdqliygIADcINChgAAsUFnFPvYOmx+GloUC4UC6wHSWyKp2qACYmBVStUsPdxARiLpqHQpAAGAA0PmEiDEkiYAHIKUSVPMYOBoBSSBCfgEmKwhnwoK4KVA5IhmCgdqJSXJxGhphpoMAUB8GVBmoqfOdAtjfKzAgBGMI0yjRWLxSkU1LQwo7OGYADMRG8Kho9CYhOJIgkUiputUEy0Oh8do1TG1bg9+riCSgVNSUBFsDUTRqiwxZCAA)